# Split array to include smaller ones based on id

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an example array:

```
arr = [{id:1, count: 2}, {id: 2, count: 6}, {id: 2, count: 4}, {id: 1, count:4}]
```

I need transform it to include arrays with objects inside based on id:

```
[[{id:1, count: 2}, {id: 1, count:4}], [{id: 2, count: 6}, {id: 2, count: 4}]]
```

If I will have 3 different ids - then it will have 3 arrays inside and so on.

If you know any good solutions - let me know. Lodash could be ok as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` from lodash to get a map like this:

```
{
    '1': [{id:1, count: 2}, {id: 1, count:4}],
    '2': [{id: 2, count: 6}, {id: 2, count: 4}]]
}
```

Then you can transform it to an array using `Object.values()`

Essentially you need these two lines:

```
const groupedById = _.groupBy(items, item => item.id);
const result = Object.values(groupedById);
```

Comment: Yep, did so. Thought maybe there is more elegant way to do that

Comment: I've edited my answer; it seems pretty elegant to me. Otherwise you could try to achieve it reduce()

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS, with `reduce`:

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let existing = acc.findIndex(elem => elem.some(obj => obj.id === curr.id));
    if (existing > -1) {
      acc[existing].push(curr);
    }
    else {
      acc[acc.length] = [curr]
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Also `(existing > -1) ? acc[existing].push(curr) : acc[acc.length] = [curr]` instead of the `if...else` block.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) solution could also work for you, then [loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) has one out of the box method [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) which can achieve your desired result.

```
import { groupBy } from "lodash";

const arr = [{id:1, count: 2}, {id: 2, count: 6}, {id: 2, count: 4}, {id: 1, count:4}]

const result = groupBy(arr, 'id');

console.log(result)
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lodash-xq8jtj)

Comment: It does not exactly what I want. In the end - it is not array, but object with 2 keys and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

@domenikk showed a really good example! Also, you could use `Ramda` instead of `Lodash` to have a point-free function =)

```js
const arr = [
  {id:1, count: 2}, 
  {id: 2, count: 6}, 
  {id: 2, count: 4}, 
  {id: 1, count:4}
]

const groupById =  R.compose(
  R.values, 
  R.groupBy(R.prop('id'))
)


console.log(groupById(arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```